# Sharing data during multi-threading - are non-static variables OK?

Tags: .net, multithreading, static, shared

In well-known [Joseph Albahari's article on Threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Creating_and_Starting_Threads), all class variables used by multiple threads are declared as `static` fields => all threads have access to the same variable. This needs to be equipped by `lock()` mechanism at all places of reading/writing and the job is done.

My question is about class property implementation. I understand it is valid if I implement (for example) property `Timeout` using `static` backing store:

```
class MyClassWithWorkerThread {
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private static int _Timeout = false;
    private int Timeout {
        get {
            lock (_locker) {
                return _Timeout;
            }
        }
        set {
            lock (_locker) {
                _Timeout = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will make variable `_Timeout` shared among all class instances.

But in my case, multi-thread processing is private to class instance. It starts with `New()` and ends with `Dispose()`. Both main thread and worker thread access `Timeout` property (but `_Timeout` backing store is never accessed outside the property getter/setter).

I do not want `_Timeout` value to be application-wide. I want to have it **unique for every class instance.** 
My question is: may I safely remove `static` from `_Timeout` variable in order to achieve this?

*Note: I'm sorry if there are any errors in the code, I'm actually using VB.NET and I converted it using a tool. I hope the main question is still clear.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely safe and pretty recommended (static variables are painful for testing even when needed). Assuming with *safe* you also mean *valid* what you don't have to forget is that:

```
this.Timeout = 0; // This is safe and valid
++this.Timeout; // This is safe but not valid
```

Because `++` operator is not atomic (that's why we have `Interlocked` class). Of course same apply in this situation:

```
if (this.Timeout == 0)
    Timeout = 10;
```

Because even if each access is *safe* (I would say reading a property is always safe but you may read an old value without `lock` barrier) it's not an atomic operation and value may change after test and before new assignment. Even more complicate?

```
if (this.Timeout == 0)
    Timeout = Timeout * 2;
```

In this case each time you read `Timeout` you may get a different value. For this reason I said lock inside the property is seldom useful unless it's a read-only property. Much better to remove that lock from property get/set and wrap your code in a lock statement:

```
lock (_locker) {
    if (this.Timeout == 0)
        Timeout = Timeout * 2;
}
```

Also note that for `int _Timeout` (I assume assignment with `false` is just a typo) you may simply remove lock and make it `volatile`:

```
private volatile int _Timeout;
```

Of course this won't solve the other described problems but it may be useful (and faster) for a read-only property (or for pretty controlled situations, `volatile` modifiers can be tricky and it has a different meaning compared with C and it's easy to forget that to *access* them is atomic but nothing more).

Comment: I fully agree with using `lock()` (VB: `SyncLock ... End SyncLock`) blocks as you describe. I actually intended to avoid scenarios you highlighted by creating local copy of `Timeout` (by single read operation) where needed, as no writes are made to it inside the class methods. I didn't make it clear in the question, but I understand that locking concept. But at least other readers will have benefit from your detailed answer, so thank you.

Comment: Volatile fields *are* very much atomic. Obviously doing two operations in order is not atomic but then neither is locking twice in sequence.

Comment: @Voo you're right, my sentence is pretty unclear: _access_ to volatile variables is atomic but operators that _seems_ to perform an atomic operation are not (like ++).

Answer (score 1):

The static keyword is orthogonal (that is: independant or unrelated to) threading.

The static keyword should only be used when you want only a single instance of that property/field/class/method/etc.

In your situation you don't need a static on _Timeout if you want that value to be unique to the instance.

I haven't read the article you link to, but I think you perhaps misunderstood it (or the author misunderstood the use of static)

Comment: Although referred article is excellent and recommended by many and many, I see that `static` is a bit overused there, even in examples where it is not necessarily required. But now, the point was made clear, thank you.

Comment: @miroxlav yes, I guess he used static almost everywhere for _simplicity_ and to keep code samples shorter (no instance objects to create and pass around). From a quick look and I think it's not something he suggest for threading, just a convenient syntax.